# How to sum inner hit score in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have a nested document like:

```
doc = {  
  "id": 1,  
  "content": [  
    {  
      "txt": apple,  
      "time": 0,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": banana,  
      "time": 1,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": water,  
      "time": 2,  
    },  
    {  
      "txt": do not match this block,  
      "time": 3,  
    },  
  ]  
}
```

When I search for "apple OR banana OR water", I get the score only from the max inner hit score, but I want to get the score from the sum of the inner hit scores.
Maybe I should use aggregation?

Answer (score -1):

adding "score_mode": "sum" in the search query